# Hiding HTML code from users?

Tags: html, hide

I tried to hide a couple of  element so that the end users can NOT see it when they see the page source. It seems NOT possible because this code will be downloaded and read by the browser. So, the user will find a way to read it.

However, I found some websites that hide part of the source! Take a look at this website: http://namechk.com/ . The source code related to the sites list is **NOT there!!** Is the code an HTML code? or it is something else that can be hided?
And any one know a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: at namechk.com/ page source available....

Comment: You can hide content through ajax, but not html

Comment: All goes from here.......   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the page heavily relies on javascript. But you can (and your browser does) download the javascripts as well. If you dig into them you will find out how the page is generated.

You can obfuscate your javascript but I don't see much point in that. Do you think your HTML is so unique that somebody would steal it?

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible to hide html code from the browser. Even in the link you posted the html code is there. It's just loaded dynamically. Have a look at the DOM in Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

The site is not showing the details because it is using Asp.net, JavaScript and jQuery to display data.

You can check it here: http://w3techs.com/sites/info/namechk.com

It is not possible to hide html from the client.

One thing you can do is remove unnecessary elements using JavasSript or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

HTML can be hidden in an iFrame, pulling the source from another page (though they could view the source from there)

Comment: I hate when people downvote with no comment.  You are unable to see the source of an iframe when looking at the source of the parent.  All you see is an iframe tag with its attributes.  It is possible to visit the source of the iframe and view it separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could load code you want to be hidden into a div via an ajax call. The content of this div won't be seen in the browser source.

```
<script>
//ajax call via jQuery/Prototype loading content into div below
    $.ajax({
        url: "somepage.php",
        data: 'yourParameters'
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#loadhtmlinviaAjax').show(); //toggle display status of this div as required
            $('#loadhtmlinviaAjax').html(data);
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="loadhtmlinviaAjax" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: You can still see it via the firebug for example. If somebody wants to steal it, she would be probably clever enough to figure it out.

Comment: That's wrong, can't see when right click-> see source code, but Firebug display html code loaded via ajax.